# Why won't my title tag change using config()?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

I'm following a tutorial where he goes on to change the `<title></title>` tag inside `index.blade.php` using `config()`.  I'm doing the same thing he's doing but for some odd reason, it isn't working for me.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Here's `index.blade.php`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>{{config('app.name', 'LSAPP')}}</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's `PagesController.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        return view('pages.index');
    }
}
```

Here's `web.php`:

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');
```

Here's a part of my `.env` file:

```
APP_NAME=LSAPP
```

Comment: What are you expecting to achieve? The syntax: config(config_name,fallback) returns the value of configuration config_name, or value "fallback" if value a does not exist. In your case you are retrieving app.name whose value is LSAPP and adding a fallback of LASPP, so in any case you should get the title to be LSAPP.

Given your description, it is hard to help you more. It would be usefull to see your config/app.php in addition to knowing what your title is after your posted code executes.

Also note that the function config(config_name, fallback) is only available from laravel 5.1 onwards

Answer (score 3):

Try running `php artisan config:cache`
It will cleared the old .env file and cachced the new one.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace app.name with name
`<title>{{config('name', ' New App Name ')}}</title>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<title>{{config('app.name')}}</title>
```

Try this. What does it print ? If it prints default value from `config/app.php` (which is Laravel by default), that means that your `.env` is wrong in some way.

By default all config values in `config/app.php` contains `env()` method. Which first parameter is key which is defined in your `.env` file and second is default value.

Here is documentation for config helper:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-config

Also you can try to enclose your .env APP_NAME value to double quotes:

```
APP_NAME="SOME VALUE"
```